# PostgreSQL concurrent update selects

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, queue, delayed-job, job-scheduling

I am attempting to have some sort of update select for a job queue. I need it to support concurrent processes affecting the same table or database This server will be used only for the queue so a database per queue is acceptable. Originally I was thinking about something like the following:

```
UPDATE state=1,ts=NOW() FROM queue WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM queue WHERE state=0 LIMIT X) RETURN *
```

Which I been reading that this will cause a race condition, I read that there was a an option for the SELECT subquery to use FOR UPDATE, but then that will lock the row and concurrent calls will be blocked where I would not mind if they skip over to the next unlocked row.

So what i am asking for is the best way to have a fifo system in postgres that requires the least amount of locking the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to wrap it in a PLPGSQL function, select FOR UPDATE NOWAIT, and then use exception handling to skip the locked rows.

This does place some additional overhead on the function because exception handling requires additional processor cycles to manage even if there are no exceptions.

As a very simple example:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_unlocked_customers() RETURNS SETOF customer
 LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
 $$
 RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM customer FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
 EXCEPTION
    WHEN LOCK_NOT_AVAILABLE THEN
    -- NO NEED TO DO ANYTHING
    END;
 END;
 $$;
```